# How to change the value of the member variables with runtime In Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

I have a tableView, I want its contentInsets is always zero. So I add the code :

```
class_replaceMethod([UITableView class], @selector(setContentInset:), (IMP)setContentInsetZero, "@");
```

then I code the `setContentInsetsZero` function:

```
void setContentInsetZero(id SELF, SEL _cmd, UIEdgeInsets insets) {

    Ivar tableViewInsets = class_getInstanceVariable([UITableView class], "_contentInset");

    object_setIvar(SELF, tableViewInsets, [NSValue valueWithUIEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero]);

}
```

when the program is running , it called `setContentInsetZero` function, but it dose not work? Could anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you're trying to do by taking the method swizzling one step further.  Treat your new method like a wrapper instead of a replacement, it can intercept the parameter and call the original.

Take a look at this link for an exact way to do what you need: http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/

This will affect all UITableViews in your application, a better solution might be subclassing UITableView and overriding the method (using a super call to pass the replaced parameter).  Then you can just use this where it is needed.

Comment: I'm try to subclass the tableView, but when I overriding the setter method, the table view have no menber variable named `_contentInsets`.

Comment: Try like:  -(void)setTableViewInsets:(??*)insets { [super setTableViewInsets:  [NSValue valueWithUIEdgeInsets: UIEdgeInsetsZero]; }